# injection of connection factory in wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jca, resource-adapter

I am trying to create a resource adapter (outbound) and deploy it in `wildfly-preview-26.0.1.Final`.
I have created a `rar` file which is deployed successfully (in the server logs I can see the tracking messages).
However, when I try to use it in a client, I get an error

```
@Path("ping")
public class JavaEE8Resource {
    
    @Resource(name = "java:/eis/Barier")
    private BarierConnectionFactory cf;

    
    @GET
    public Response ping(){
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("origin", cf);
       
        
        return Response
                .ok(map.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

> UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/api/v1/ping: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.sample.test.api.BarierConnectionFactory field org.sample.test.war.resources.JavaEE8Resource.cf to org.sample.test.ra.out.BarierConnectionFactoryImpl

if change customer so

```
@Path("ping")
public class JavaEE8Resource {
    
    @Resource(name = "java:/eis/Barier")
    private Object cf;

    
    @GET
    public Response ping(){
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("origin", cf);
       
        
        return Response
                .ok(map.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I receive

> {origin=org.sample.test.ra.out.BarierConnectionFactoryImpl@4f17b2db}

but when I try to cast from Object I get

```
@Path("ping")
public class JavaEE8Resource {
    
    @Resource(name = "java:/eis/Barier")
    private Object cf;

    
    @GET
    public Response ping(){
        
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("origin", (BarierConnectionFactory) cf);
       
        
        return Response
                .ok(map.toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.sample.test.ra.out.BarierConnectionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to class org.sample.test.api.BarierConnectionFactory (org.sample.test.ra.out.BarierConnectionFactoryImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.barier.rar' @7cf3ac33; org.sample.test.api.BarierConnectionFactory is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.test-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war' @412d2a9e)

The interface and implementation are separated into separate modules (jar files).

--- Update ---

The problem is that both modules include a module with the public interface (api) declarations.

I solved the problem by removing the corresponding module from the war file (which, logically, led to a `ClassDefNotFoundException`) so I used `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in which I specified a dependency on the module with the resource adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.barier.rar"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

However, this approach requires knowing the module name with the resource adapter. For now this is not a problem, but I wish I could find a cleaner solution. So, assume the question is relevant.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using WildFly Preview? It would require a migration to Jakarta EE 9. If you've made that migration, you're better to use WildFly 29.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins the reason is not reasonable :) . I am starting a new project and I want it to be with the latest version of the platform in order to save myself a migration in the future. otherwise, you are indeed right that I should update the server to the latest version.

Comment: WildFly 26 Preview is Jakarta EE 9.1 which is effectively Jakarta EE 8 with the namespace rename. WildFly 27+ is Jakarta EE 10. There is likely not much value in using Jakarta EE 9.1 TBH.